# How to interpret MeanDecreaseGini, what does the numbers mean on the scale?

Tags: r, random-forest, decision-tree, interpretation, gini

I have to interpret the most important variables by speaking about the MeanDecreaseGini in randomForest.
For example, I have variable x, with a value of 250. How can you explain that 250? What does that 250 mean?

Comment: This question should probably be moved over to CV. https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It doesn't have an interpretation, it is only relatively comparable with the other values.